# Microservice, is it more suited to NoSQL

Tags: nosql, microservices

Using microservice would mean it's not possible to achieve third normal form or I would have to duplicate data. Then that would mean using microservice I would have to use NoSQL, right?

Comment: microservice has nothing to do with database design

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not necessarily a requirement.  A microservice can use any kind of storage back-end it likes, and still be a microservice.  In fact, several microservices may indeed use the same back-end thus keeping 3rd normal form across services.

Another way to look at this is that the 3rd normal form only exists from the point of view of the data access, so while the overall application consisting of many microservices may not be in 3rd normal form, each microservice itself may be in 3rd normal form.

Finally, there's no requirement that SQL databases be in 3rd normal form.  This is simply an architectural goal, not a technological requirement.

Comment: Maybe each microservice can achieve its own 3rd normal form, but it's still connected to other microservices that share relationships between tables. So that would me microservice would have to call another one update their tables, right

Comment: Yes, one architecture of a service mesh is that each service is responsible for their own domain, so that the overall set of microservices achieve 3rd normal form.  Most microservice implementations eventually evolve to this architecture, though now you must account for cross-service authn/authz (generally achieved using JWT to avoid bottlenecking on an auth service or similar).

Comment: Then, usually, microservice has several tables to avoid being tightly coupled?

Comment: Also, as a point of order, it's generally bad practice to have services directly call each other as this couples them and reduces (sometimes eliminates) their independence.  Better to have services interact with a messaging plane or broker, not directly with each other.

Comment: Good point @MikahBarnett, though you can still get tight coupling if the broker is too thin, or the services too inflexible.  Don't forget to be permissive in what you accept (and strict in what you produce) as either a relying party or service.

Comment: The microservice has exactly the tables or datasources (in the case of something other than a table-oriented architecture) it needs to do its job, no more (and hopefully no less).  Study this: https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/antoine_de_saintexupery_121910

Comment: I won't use a broker, I will rely on rest API. It still has to include the token after the authentication service, so I guess if there's a relation between other tables. That would have to be included in the rest API too

Comment: Brokers or locators are useful in case the API changes, and you need to mediate a versioning update, or if the location changes and needs to be routed differently.  Strong service mesh managers like Istio can help as well as dealing with multiple versions and deployment rollovers.  Would advise against having no manager in your service mesh.

Comment: Just because "microservice" has "micro" in the name, does not mean that it's easier to manage.